# C# linq query OUTER APPLY with SUM

Tags: linq, sum, apply, outer-join

Trying to convert a SQL Query to Linq:

```
SELECT GrossInvoiceAmount, C.SumOfPayments
  FROM invoice
OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT SUM(SumOfPayments) AS SumOfPayments FROM vw_sumOfPayments
  WHERE vw_sumOfPayments.PaymentDate = '01/01/2010 00:00:00'
      AND vw_sumOfPayments.InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId
) C
WHERE LastTransmitDate = '01/01/2010 00:00:00'
```

I have this in my C# code. It runs and gives results, but the `invoice.GrossInvoiceAmount` amount is wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var InvoiceQuery = (from invoice in this.Context.Invoices
        join payment in this.Context.vw_sumOfPayments.Where(pay => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pay.PaymentDate) >= startdate 
                                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pay.PaymentDate) <= enddate) 
                on invoice.InvoiceID equals payment.InvoiceID into pays
        select new InvoiceModel{

           InvoiceTypeId = invoice.InvoiceTypeId,
           InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvoiceNumber,
           InvoiceDate = invoice.InvoiceDate,
           InvoiceAmount = invoice.GrossInvoiceAmount,
           PaymentAmount = pays.AsEnumerable().Sum(o => o.SumOfPayments)

         });
```

Comment: Should have mentioned. I think the SUM(SumOfPayments) inside of the OUTER APPLY is what I am missing. That SUM needs to be there, or the GrossInvoiceAmount won't be right.

Comment: Linq... Linq-to..what?